# Google cloud create sql instances inside a VPC

Tags: security, google-cloud-sql, vpc

I was wondering if it was possible to secure the sql instances isolating them inside a VPC. I havn't seen anything in the documentation that would link the VPC and sql services of Google.

Is that possible to do that and if not, is there any way of using VPC to secure the sql service ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CloudSQL does not support VPC at the moment.

Comment: I think still CloudSQL does not support VPC.